# Typical dimension of eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

Let $S$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices $A$, for which one of $A$'s eigenvalues has multiplicity $m$.  We know the corresponding eigenspace of $A$ has dimension $1\le d\le m$.  What is the likely value of $d$, as $A$ varies over $S$?

For example, out of $2\times 2$ matrices $\left[\begin{array}{cc}p&q\\r&s\end{array}\right]$ with double eigenvalue $0$, there is a single matrix (the zero matrix) with a two-dimensional eigenspace, but a two-parameter set of matrices with a one-dimensional eigenspace.  You just need $p+s=0$ and $ps-qr=0$.

Comment: It can be any integer satisfying $1\le d\le m$. What do you mean by “likely value”?

Comment: As the example shows for the 2x2, the eigenspace is almost certainly 1-dimensional.  I guess I am asking, more generally, how many degrees-of-freedom in the set of nxn matrices with an eigenvalue of multiplicity m and eigemspace of dimension d.

Comment: The $2\times2$ case is misleading; a $2\times2$ matrix with just one eigenvalue is diagonalizable if and only if it *is* diagonal.